# can I compile Monodevelop in Ubuntu Hardy (8.04)?

Tags: xubuntu, monodevelop

I haven't been able to figure out if there's a way for me to get the latest version of MonoDevelop in Hardy. Would someone be able to help?

Comment: have you tried?  what have you tried so far?  where are you stuck?

Comment: ya, i did. a while back, and i gave up, even though i'm no newbie. i asked this because i thought there was going to be a straight yes-no answer, so as to devote the time to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. But you need updated [Mono](http://badgerports.org/hardy.html) also. Then, you can compile it (if it doesn't depend on something else besides mono.).

(Usual way:
1) `sudo apt-get build-dep monodevelop build-essential`
2) `cd /where/the/monodevelop/source/is/`
3) `./configure --prefix=/usr` #here you configure it up. Type `./configure --help` to see your options. It'll also check for dependencies, it'll tell you if you still miss something.
4) `make` #basically you make the binaries in this step
5) `sudo make install` #this will actually install it

(NOTE! I wrote the "usual way". There is no guarantee that this will work. Make sure you READ the README/INSTALL file in the source folder of Monodevelop. Also, keep the source folder (what you used for install). You will be able to delete it later using this folder and issuing the command: `sudo make uninstall`.)